# Mixing dependencies like I did in DNX in RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a new project in ASP.NET Core RC2, this is my project.json:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication5-0d78a904-732a-4150-99d4-59bc7ce1e647",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "PayPal": "1.7.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I need to add sime libraries like "Paypal", "MongoDB Driver", "AutoMapper", "RestSharp", etc. But I have this error:

> The dependency X does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version=1.0

I have tried changing the "frameworks" with errors:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": { }
  }
```

> The dependency X does not support framework .NETFramework,
>   Version=4.5.1

In RC1 I can mix dependencies, but now, I don't know how... Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I have update my project.json like @Tseng says, but I can't use the MongoDb Driver yet... This is my new *project.json*:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-WebApplication5-0d78a904-732a-4150-99d4-59bc7ce1e647",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "MongoDB.Driver": "2.2.3"
    },
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net451+win8" ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final"

      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `Microsoft.NETCore.App` doesn't work with .NET 4.51 for obvious reason, it's called NETCore for a reason. What other depedencies throw it?

Comment: Ok, but in RC1 It worked...

Comment: @Tseng I have read this article, with no results... http://ardalis.com/how-to-target-netcoreapp-and-net461-from-aspnet-core

Comment: No, there was no `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in RC1

Comment: Ok, but I could use rc1 libraries from .NET and other libraries, I just use dnx451 like my framework

Comment: @Tseng If for example I need to use PayPal nuget package, and PayPal doesn't have the Nuget Package compatible with RC2 I'm not goint to be able to use it? With RC1 I can use it... but now in RC2, I can't...

Comment: because with dnx the runtime was preinstalled. This is not the case anymore in dotnet cli. You need to reference the runtime explictely and it only runs on .NET Core. for full .NET framework you don't need this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114657/discussion-between-chemitaxis-and-tseng).

Comment: How can I use Paypal dependencies in ASP.NET Core RC2 app?

Comment: You can use dnxcore50 packages in netcoreapp1.0/netstandardapp1.x apps by adding "imports" for a given framework. Something like this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7233bea2176fe2810cfe4db447fe2fc620a80ab2/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Specification.Tests/project.json#L28. Forcing other packages is a russian roulette so you should avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an extended explanation: `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and the `NETStandard.Library` are metapackages, they will include all of the .NET Core framework assemblies needed to run. Before that, dnx was responsible for loading these into the ASP.NET Core application (and dnvm for downloading/installing the assemblies).

If you depend on assemblies that are not ported yet to .NET Core, you have to target .NET 4.5.1 and remove the `NETStandard.Library` (for class libraries) and `Microsoft.NETCore.App` for applications.

i.e.

```
{
    "userSecretsId" : "aspnet-WebApplication5-0d78a904-732a-4150-99d4-59bc7ce1e647",
    "dependencies" : {
        "MongoDB.Driver" : "2.2.4",
        ...
    },

    "frameworks" : {
        "net451" : {}
    },
}
```

and then **remove** all references (this includes `using` namespace declarations as well as any type from an assembly that do not support .NET Core yet) to non .NET Core libraries/types (i.e. using `#if` preprocessor directives) or just **completely remove** `netcoreapp1.0` and always target the full .NET Framework (which requires you to run have either Mono or .NET Framework installed on the server you want to run it later on).

This is unrelated to rc2 or library support for it. If your PayPal library supports net45 or net451 target, it will work. But not on .NET Core, just when targeting the full framework.

Comment: I have tested it, with no results... I can't access from a Controller for example to mongo dependency...